# best performance for storing notifications in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a question concerning the performance of 2 different options, which one is better?

Explanation:
I have 5 tables in a postgresql db: users, followers, posts, likes and comments. They look like this (simplified):

```
users (
  user_id bigint,
  username character varying(24)
);
followers (
  follower_id bigint,
  user_id bigint,
  following_user_id bigint,
  timestamp timestamp with time zone DEFAULT NOW()
);
post (
  post_id bigint,
  user_id bigint,
  text text,
  timestamp timestamp with time zone DEFAULT NOW()
);
likes (
  like_id bigint,
  post_id bigint,
  user_id bigint,
  timestamp timestamp with time zone DEFAULT NOW()
);
comments (
  comment_id bigint,
  post_id bigint,
  user_id bigint,
  comment text,
  timestamp timestamp with time zone DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

I now want to make a notifications component in my app to show someone he received a new like or comment on a post.

**FIRST OPTION:**

The first option (I have now) is to create a sixth table named notifications:

```
notifications (
  notification_id bigint,
  type character varying(12),
  g_user_id bigint,
  r_user_id bigint,
  s_user_id bigint,
  post_id bigint,
  timestamp timestamp with time zone DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

A notification row would look like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| notification_id | type   | g_user_id | r_user_id | s_user_id | post_id | timestamp    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1               | post   | 1         | NULL      | NUL       | 1       | 2021-01-01...|
| 2               | comm   | NULL      | 2         | 1         | 1       | 2021-01-01...|
| 3               | like   | NULL      | 1         | 2         | 1       | 2021-01-01...|
| ...                                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It seems to me this is the **easiest solution**, a query to select and order the notifications for a user (and fetch meta-data like the username of the sender_user_id) is easy with a JOIN.

The problem I'm facing is: I have more notification types (not only likes and comments but around 20 different notification types). Some notifications are for a user specific (defined in receiving_user_id), some notifications are 'general' and are for all users following an account (I defince this in general_user_id).

My (simplified) query to fetch these notifications now look like this. I'm selecting all notifications for r_user_id (receiving_user_id) 1 with a JOIN to the table users to select all usernames from the sending_user_ids (s_user_id) (if not null) and to select all "general" notifications (all notifications with g_user_id NOT NULL where g_user_id is a user_id that user_id = 1 is following in the table followers).

```
SELECT
    a.notification_id,
    a.type,
    a.timestamp,
    b.username
FROM
    notifications a
LEFT JOIN
    users b
  ON
    a.s_user_id = b.user_id
WHERE
    (
      a.r_user_id = 1
      OR
      a.g_user_id IN (SELECT following_user_id FROM followers WHERE user_id = 1)
    )
ORDER BY
    a.timestamp DESC
```

**The biggest problem I have with this solution is that it requires an extra table and extra commands in my node.JS code. When someone likes a post, I have to create a notification row, when some dislikes a post, I have to delete this notification again.**

**SECOND OPTION:**

My second option is to just leave these 5 tables and with a UNION ALL query "create" the notifications on the fly, if possible.

I don't know how other people create a notification system, and I didn't found much tutorials about it. Is it OK to create a separate notifications table (and use postgresql trigger functions to automatically create/delete notification rows), or should I create these notifications 'on the fly' based on the rows in likes, comments and posts?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with creating a dedicated table for `notifications`, along the route your example above is choosing to take. Whether you use **triggers** or handle managing it with calls from the application side is up to you and equally of merit as well.

Alternatively I was thinking similar to your last proposed solution, but by using a **View** as a way to centralize the different notification types and stay current in real-time. You would `UNION ALL` your different notification types and when you select from the View, you would likely order by the `timestamp` descending to show the latest notifications first.

The only other part you'd need to come up with is how to manage which notifications a user has already seen. For that you'd likely need a logging table of the notification's `id` and `type`, and had columns for the user's `id` and `timestamp` of when they viewed their notifications. Then in the View above you'd `OUTER JOIN` to this viewed notifications log, so you can have an additional column in it called `isNew` and you'd know which ones are new to the current user since the last time they looked at their notifications. At least this *viewed notifications log* table would be written to less frequently (only whenever a user looks at their notifications) than just a pure `notifications` table (every new instance of a notification), so it would be much transactionally lighter.